# javascript sort and sort equals on result. how?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a problem sorting objects of structure {"name", "count"}:

```
1. name => "aaa", count => 1
2. name => "bbb", count => 2
3. name => "ccc", count => 3
4. name => "ddd", count => 1
5. name => "eee", count => 1
```

I need to sort this on "count" (small to big, then big to small).

My sort function:

```
mass.sort(compareElements);

function compareElements(a, b)
{
 if(a < b) return -1;
 else if(a > b) return 1;
 else return 0;
}
```

On first call (small to big) I get one result 'res1'
on second call (big to small) I get result 'res2'
on third call (small to big again) I get 'res3' !== 'res1' !!

The order of the elements in res1 and res3 is not the same. I need them to be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make you sort [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), you will need to compare the "equal" items by their index:

```
// mass = [{name:…, count:…}, {name:…, count:…}, …]
for (var i=0; i<mass.length; i++)
    mass[i].index = i;
mass.sort(function(a, b) {
    return compareElements(a, b) || a.index - b.index;
});
function compareElements(a, b) {
    // something
    return a.count - b.count;
}
```

Comment: mass.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.count.toString().localeCompare(b.count.toString())
})
Isn't this much simpler?

Comment: @VimalMahi No, that does a completely different thing - and is not stable

Comment: OK. I will dig more deep into that

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are like:

```
var arrObj = {
   name: "aaa",
   count: 1
};
```

Use this function for comparing:

```
function compareElements(a, b)
{
  return a.count - b.count;
}
```